# Access to instance variables created by RSpec assign in view test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am again attempting to please rubocop-rails.  In this case, the view spec generated by `rails generate scaffold` uses instance variables (e.g. @import_file)

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'import_files/edit', type: :view do
  before do
    @import_file = assign(:import_file, ImportFile.create!(
                                          path: 'MyString',
                                          file_type: 1
                                        ))
  end

  it 'renders the edit import_file form' do
    render

    assert_select 'form[action=?][method=?]', import_file_path(@import_file), 'post' do
      assert_select 'input[name=?]', 'import_file[path]'

      assert_select 'input[name=?]', 'import_file[file_type]'
    end
  end
end
```

The RSpec Style guide does not like [Instance Variables](https://rspec.rubystyle.guide/#instance-variables).

The code already uses `assign` which is required since this is a view spec.  How do I get access to that variable?  Simply referencing it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few Stack Exchange questions that mention `view_assigns` but I thought this question / answer was worth while.  Access to the variable created by `assign` is access via `view_assigns[symbol]`

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'import_files/edit', type: :view do
  subject { document_root_element }

  let(:path) { import_file_path(view_assigns[:import_file]) }
  let(:form_css) { "form[action='#{path}'][method=post]" }

  before do
    assign(:import_file, create(:import_file))
    render
  end

  it { is_expected.to have_css(form_css) }

  describe 'the rendered form' do
    subject { css_select form_css }

    it { is_expected.to have_field('Path', type: :file, name: 'import_file[path]') }
    it { is_expected.to have_select('File type', name: 'import_file[file_type]', options: %w[qif sqlite]) }
  end
end
```